# NYC Open data DOB Missing Information

Tags: socrata, soda

I am facing some issue in NYC department of building API.
help me if you know any other API giving the same information
I have used this API but didn't work for me
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/83x8-shf7.json

Missing fields
permitee detailed address

https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/83x8-shf7.json?$where=filing_date BETWEEN '2018-05-01T06:00:00' AND '2018-05-30T10:00:00'

Also i am not able get expected data using filters for "filing_date" from same api
expected data should return all data between 2018-05-01 and 2018-05-30 for this API But i am getting only few results.

**I am getting this data**

[
    {
        "bin__": "3118313",
        "bldg_type": "1",
        "block": "05143",
        "borough": "BROOKLYN",
        "city": "BROOKLYN",
        "community_board": "314",
        "dobrundate": "2018-05-03T00:00:00.000",
        "expiration_date": "2018-06-11T00:00:00.000",
        "filing_date": "2018-05-02T00:00:00.000",
        "filing_status": "INITIAL",
        "gis_census_tract": "1522",
        "gis_council_district": "40",
        "gis_latitude": "40.641731",
        "gis_longitude": "-73.966432",
        "gis_nta_name": "Flatbush",
        "house__": "328",
        "issuance_date": "2018-05-02T00:00:00.000",
        "job__": "321679046",
        "job_doc___": "01",
        "job_start_date": "2018-05-02T00:00:00.000",
        "job_type": "A2",
        "lot": "00068",
        "non_profit": "N",
        "owner_s_business_name": "N/A",
        "owner_s_business_type": "INDIVIDUAL",
        "owner_s_first_name": "MATTHEW",
        "owner_s_house__": "328",
        "owner_s_house_street_name": "ARGYLE ROAD",
        "owner_s_last_name": "LIMA",
        "owner_s_phone__": "3475968096",
        "owner_s_zip_code": "11218",
        "permit_sequence__": "01",
        "permit_si_no": "3452932",
        "permit_status": "ISSUED",
        "permit_subtype": "OT",
        "permit_type": "EW",
        "permittee_s_business_name": "BMB BUILDER INC",
        "permittee_s_first_name": "YUAN HANG",
        "permittee_s_last_name": "XIAO",
        "permittee_s_license__": "0612790",
        "permittee_s_license_type": "GC",
        "permittee_s_phone__": "9175776544",
        "residential": "YES",
        "self_cert": "N",
        "site_fill": "NOT APPLICABLE",
        "state": "NY",
        "street_name": "ARGYLE ROAD",
        "superintendent_business_name": "BMB BUILDER INC",
        "superintendent_first___last_name": "YUAN HANG XIAO",
        "work_type": "OT",
        "zip_code": "11218"
    }]

**Expected Data should be**

[{
        "bin__": "1090379",
        "bldg_type": "2",
        "block": "00760",
        "borough": "MANHATTAN",
        "city": "GREAT NECK",
        "community_board": "104",
        "dobrundate": "2018-05-02T00:00:00.000",
        "expiration_date": "2018-10-28T00:00:00.000",
        "filing_date": "2018-05-01T00:00:00.000",
        "filing_status": "RENEWAL",
        "gis_census_tract": "111",
        "gis_council_district": "3",
        "gis_latitude": "40.753978",
        "gis_longitude": "-73.993673",
        "gis_nta_name": "Hudson Yards-Chelsea-Flatiron-Union Square",
        "house__": "337",
        "issuance_date": "2018-05-01T00:00:00.000",
        "job__": "121187606",
        "job_doc___": "01",
        "job_start_date": "2016-02-19T00:00:00.000",
        "job_type": "NB",
        "lot": "00020",
        "non_profit": "N",
        "owner_s_business_name": "HKONY WEST 36 LLC",
        "owner_s_business_type": "PARTNERSHIP",
        "owner_s_first_name": "SAM",
        "owner_s_house__": "420",
        "owner_s_house_street_name": "GREAT NECK ROAD",
        "owner_s_last_name": "CHANG",
        "owner_s_phone__": "9178380886",
        "owner_s_zip_code": "11021",
        "permit_sequence__": "07",
        "permit_si_no": "3451790",
        "permit_status": "ISSUED",
        "permit_type": "NB",
        "permittee_s_business_name": "OMNIBUILD CONSTRUCTION IN",
        "permittee_s_first_name": "PETER",
        "permittee_s_last_name": "SERPICO",
        "permittee_s_license__": "0608390",
        "permittee_s_license_type": "GC",
        "permittee_s_phone__": "2124191930",
        "self_cert": "N",
        "site_fill": "ON-SITE",
        "site_safety_mgr_s_first_name": "ROBERT",
        "site_safety_mgr_s_last_name": "FILIPPONE",
        "special_district_1": "GC",
        "state": "NY",
        "street_name": "W 36 ST",
        "zip_code": "10018"
    }]

Answer (score 0):

Combing through the JSON, it appears that these columns are not matching: `permit_subtype`, `superintendent_business_name`, `superintendent_first___last_name`, `site_safety_mgr_s_first_name`, `site_safety_mgr_s_last_name`, and `special_district_1`.

Looking at the original data sources, the columns that do not match are instances where the field is blank for that field. That is, `bin__ = 1090379` does not have a `permit_subtype`, so it is omitted in the JSON (which is standard practice).

It will, however, be included in the CSV output since that format must include all columns: `https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/83x8-shf7.csv?$where=filing_date%20BETWEEN%20%272018-05-01T06:00:00%27%20AND%20%272018-05-30T10:00:00%27`.

This answer took a bit of digging because it wasn't immediately obvious which columns were different between the two examples. It's always helpful to over-explain to make it easier to track-down the issue.

Likewise, per the `filing_date` question, please include the query you're attempting to use.